# boot menu two windows 10 and 8.1, move boot settings from 10 to 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, ssd, windows-8.1

I have two windows from two separated Storage Drives,

1-new 240GB SSD disk, win 8.1(new OS, installed last week)

2- win 10(old OS, installed 2 years ago and used before, and now I need it some times)

, how move all OS boot menu settings from win 10 to win 8.1 and use OS menu from win 8.1 instead of win 10?

when I press power button of laptop, display boot OS menu from win 10
and I want change it to win 8.1

not change first boot OS to win 8.1, I want change all settings of booting from win 10 to win 8.1

Comment: "how move all OS boot menu settings from win 10 to win 8.1" - Edit your BCD and change the default entry to your desired choice.  What settings exactly are you looking to transfer?

Answer (score 0):

You may change the default bootloader using the
[BCDEdit command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdedit-command-line-options).

Run CMD as Administrator and enter the following commands:

- View the current default operating system entry:

  ```
    bcdedit /enum {bootmgr}
  ```
- List all existing entries; note the `identifier` for the entry that you want
  to be the default:

  ```
    bcdedit /enum
  ```
- To set a new default (where `<id>` is the `identifier` for the new entry):

  ```
    bcdedit /default <id>
  ```